# "invalid multibyte char" error when using greek characters in Rails enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, ruby-1.9.3

This:

```
enum UnitOfMeasure: [ :g, :mg, :µg]
```

gives:

```
Syntax Error: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
```

I hope I won't be forced to add a table just for this.

Comment: What's your Ruby version?

Comment: Using ruby-1.9.3-p392

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3 defaults to US-ASCII encoding (see [tadman's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42409188/477037) for a quick fix). You should upgrade to Ruby 2.x, it is the [recommended Ruby version](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#ruby-versions) for Rails 4 and above.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was running code directly in the console, I which I couldn't just add `# encoding: UTF-8`, the solution under this situation is to set 2 environment variables:

```
$ export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then you just only need to run `rails c`, and you'll be able to use the characters you desire, in my case I tried to use Russian characters.

Comment: This is just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using a newer version of Ruby where UTF-8 encoding is the default you may need to add this to your file:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

If that doesn't fix it, be sure that your file is actually saved as UTF-8.

Comment: After putting the magic comment now I get "Syntax Error:  invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)"

Comment: @kranz make sure that your file is actually UTF-8 encoded (you need a UTF-8 aware editor).

Comment: @kranz If you have access to the `file` command, make sure your file is actually UTF-8. It's often the case that it's saved as something else by accident.